# Service not sending emails nor logging

Tags: c#

I have a service running on a Windows 2012 server.  When I first started the service a log entry was made and an email was sent.  It is still running but no notifications are being generated.  The service is suppose to watch a SFTP folder and notify when a csv file has been delivered.  The first and only notification indicated that the file was renamed from tmp to csv.  What do I have to change to make this work consistently?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace FileWatcherService
{
    public partial class fileWatcherService : ServiceBase
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher m_Watcher;
        private bool m_bDirty;

        public fileWatcherService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("DFC Windows File Service"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("DFC Windows File Service", "DFC Log");
            }

            eventLogger.Source = "DFC Windows File Service";
            eventLogger.Log = "DFC Log";

            var sftp_input = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatcherPath"];

            m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sftp_input, "LoanTape*.csv");

            m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                     | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            m_Watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            m_Watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            m_Watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            m_Watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
            m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                eventLogger.WriteEntry("DFC Loan Tape file watcher service started");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                eventLogger.WriteEntry("Loan Tape file watcher: Error in startup: " + e.Message);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLogger.WriteEntry("DFC Loan Tape file watcher service stopped");
        }

        private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!m_bDirty)
            {
                string emailMsg = "Loan Tape: " + e.Name + " is available for processing";
                var email_distribution = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRecipients"].Split(',');
                var serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
                SendMessage(serverName + " DFC: Loan Tape Available", emailMsg, email_distribution);
                m_bDirty = true;
                eventLogger.WriteEntry("DFC Loan Tape available");
            }
        }

        private void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!m_bDirty)
            {
                string emailMsg = "Loan Tape: " + e.Name + " is available for processing";
                var email_distribution = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRecipients"].Split(',');
                var serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
                SendMessage(serverName + " DFC: Loan Tape Available", emailMsg, email_distribution);
                m_bDirty = true;
                eventLogger.WriteEntry("DFC Loan Tape available");
                m_Watcher.Filter = e.Name;
                m_Watcher.Path = e.FullPath.Substring(0, e.FullPath.Length - m_Watcher.Filter.Length);
            }
        }

        private void SendMessage(string msgSubject, string msgBody, string[] email_distribution = null)
        {
            if (email_distribution == null)
            {
                email_distribution = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRecipients"].Split(',');
            }

            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            foreach (string email in email_distribution)
            {
                mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
            }
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSender"], "DFC Loan Tape Service");
            mailMsg.Subject = msgSubject;
            mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMsg.Body = msgSubject + ":" + Environment.NewLine + msgBody;

            mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgBody, new ContentType("text/html")));

            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

                smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                eventLogger.WriteEntry("Error in sending Email msg" + Environment.NewLine + "Error is: " + e.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Catching `SmtpException`s and discarding/ignoring the `InnerException` makes it nearly impossible to write stable/working programs, IMO.

Comment: Understood but the problem is not with sending the email, its with the service which is not seeing the file being dropped.  I know the email process works as this is common code running in many applications.

Comment: `SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587))` why is this code here..? `587` is already an integer remove the `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: Don´t jump the gun, important information is lacking to give a good answer, so who is to say 587 is an integer and not the name of another variable?

It can be bad written legacy code being upgraded, or just not following best practices.. I can´t see 587 being defined as an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looking for a bug, fix your logic.

You are only doing work in your handlers if a flag is set. The problem is that your handlers set this flag, which means they never do work after the first time.

```
if (!m_bDirty)
{
    // some work
    m_bDirty = true;
    // some other work
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. that is what I was just looking at .. once it is set to true it never gets reset.

Comment: dang, I answered it the same minute, but mark Seths answer as the answer since you found the help from his post, and it answers it quite clearly, and it is important to mark answers so others will find the best answers

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to understand the entire logic from what you provided, but

```
OnRenamed
```

changes

```
m_bDirty to true
```

so you need to change it to false in the beginning of the other methods before checking if it is false again, but it is hard to give a good answer since the information is lacking

Answer (score 0):

Think problem you have got is events will fired continously as you have hooked to all events of filewatcher. You need to collect events and fire them one after another.
1. Start a thread in the constructor:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.DoWork));
   thread.Start();
```

2. Create an eventdata class to hold the message and event data.

   private class FileEventData
           {
               public string FileName { get; set; }
               public string Message { get; set; }
           }
3. Create a concurrent list to hold the data.

   private ConcurrentBag  fileEventDatas = new ConcurrentBag();
4. Thread will now start sending the events from the list:

```html
    private void DoWork()
                {
                    //control for shutdown using a flag
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (fileEventDatas.Count > 0)
                        {
                            FileEventData data;
                            fileEventDatas.TryTake(out data);
                            SendMessage(serverName + " DFC: Loan Tape Available", data.Message, this.email_distribution);
                            eventLogger.WriteEntry("DFC Loan Tape available");
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

5. In the events, add the events to the list:

```html
 private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
                    string emailMsg = "Loan Tape: " + e.Name + " is available for processing";
                    FileEventData fileEventData = new FileEventData()
                    {
                        FileName = e.Name,
                        Message = emailMsg,
                    };
                    this.fileEventDatas.Add(fileEventData);
                }
```